# Why is my website not using the fonts I specified? No access to the font?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fonts

I am using Rails and have specified my fonts as follows:

```
#Application.html.erb includes in the head:
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

#One of the stylesheets includes:
body{ font-family: 'Indie Flower', sans-serif; }
```

I'm also using the Bootstrap gem (which perhaps is overriding the above?).

On the development server, however, my site does not use the fonts I specified. I think it's Helvetica instead. What am I doing wrong?

I also checked with the inspector, which gives the following information:

- For `body` is says `font-family: "Indie Flower",sans-serif;`.
- For example, for the next `div` it says the same.
- The `h3` within the `div` says `font-family: inherit;`.
- Same for the `h5` within the `div`.
- For `p` within the `div` it says `font-family: "Indie Flower",sans-serif;`

So you would expect the font to indeed be Indie Flower but it isn't. I also checked it using another font, and again all text shows up as what I belief to be is Helvetica instead of the font I specified.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Update:** `application.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= render 'shared/shim' %>
</head>
<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried it by moving the font up above the stylesheet, but this made no difference.

And `application.css`:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker3
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

---

**Update 2:** Removing the fonts from `application.html.erb` confirms it does not show the right font. In the inspector it has the right font specified. However, it's not actually using that font it. Similarly, I could specify in the css a font-family with some random name and it shows the same font as it does now.

I have the impression therefore that it's correctly specified in the css but the app does not have access to the font and therefore falls back on verdana. Perhaps the app is unable to load the font? But why would that be or why would it not have access to the font? I tried different google fonts and belief their source was each time correctly specified in `application.html.erb`. What to do?

Comment: Is the code setting the font below the bootstrap and such?

Comment: Please post your application.css.

Comment: I added application.css to the original post.

Comment: Bootstrap is included by adding two lines in one of the css files: `@import "bootstrap-sprockets";` `@import "bootstrap";`. The Gemfile includes `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.4.1'`.

Comment: Try creating a custom .css file (like 'test.css' and include it in your application.css ( *= require test ), but make sure you add it after any bootstrap lines, and obviously, make sure it includes css to use your font. I'm thinking you're looking at a pipeline load order issue.

Comment: @MarsAtomic, not completely sure what you mean. I agree with that it might very well be a pipeline load order issue (or otherwise it might be unable to access the font and is therefore falling back on a standard font?). I created an additional file `test.css.scss` and included here only: `body { font-family: 'Indie Flower', sans-serif; }`. But since I don't have any control which css file is loaded first/last, I don't see how this would help. I tried it but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause. The source of the font needed to be `https` instead of `http`. So:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

This is pretty tricky since all the links offered on the web to include in your own app use "http".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body{
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}
```

Comment: Then I do indeed get a different font type but not the one that I'm looking for. I also tried `cursive` with another font. And again the font is then exactly the same as for `font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;`. So `cursive` indeed has an effect, but it doesn;t seem to be applying the font-family since irrespective which font-family I use, it shows up the same.

Comment: What webbrowser are you using currently? What happens if you try a different browser?

Comment: I'm currently using the latest Firefox. I just also tried Chrome but the result is the same.